# IE File Explorer View not showing files

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

I have a library in SharePoint online site with nested folder structure. When I opened one of the folder in "IE explore view" it's not showing files but can see in SharePoint site. I am facing this issue with particular folder only.

Can someone help what would be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the "problem" folder contain items with very long names? It is a known issue with Explorer View that it cannot cope with that.
Paul | SLIM Applications

Comment: Yes, it has with very long names. Do you know what's the maximum file name length?

Comment: If you stay below 256 it should work. It is confusing for users because SharePoint Online allows 400 characters for the path length. See https://chuvash.eu/2019/10/31/the-path-length-limit-of-400-chars-in-sharepoint-online/ for some more info how the path length is calculated.